# A term for the property of being able to be accessed by many people?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

How do I say that a given object has the **property that it can be accessed by many people**? I am trying to use that property in a sentence as follows:

> *Y* is unreliable since it inherits the *property above* of *X*

My current attempt is:

> *Y* is unreliable since it inherits the ubiquitous accessibility of *X*

Are there better ways to convey the idea described above?

Comment: Your attempt isn't bad, but I might choose "universal accessibility" over "ubiquitous." Even better, especially if the context doesn't elaborate much, might simply be to explain as clearly as you did in this question: "... since it can be accessed by many people, a property it inherits from X."

Comment: *promiscuity*? That kind of means accessible to many people, but you don't make it clear 
if you're looking for an existing computer-sciencey word or are are happy to take a metaphor from somewhere else.

Comment: @AndyBonner I don't think "universal" is suitable, since it implies that *everyone* may access *X*, which is not what I mean. I think your second suggestion is great, thank you!

Comment: @StuartF Spot on - but I was hesitant to add computer-sciencey context as that might make the question too restrictive.

Comment: If we *do* go comp-sci-ey, there's "... it inherits the *multi-user access* of X," unless we're not really talking about a context that controlled.

Comment: A sunset or a television program can be accessed by many people without being damaged or changed.

Comment: *Y is unreliable since it grants permissions inherited from X.*